# vim:how to set taglist and nerdtree at one vertical split screen

Tags: vim, nerdtree, taglist

As pictrue,I think you can understand me. I try to set .vimrc for taglist:

```
let Tlist_Use_Horiz_Window=1
```

or

```
let Tlist_Use_Right_Window = 1
```

it does work of course.

I try to C+W + H|J|K|L,fail again...

Who is familiar with vim, help me please.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a vim plugin '[winmanager](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1440)'. It can set the layout like your description. There are lots of blogs introducing how to set it work with NERDTree and taglist/tagbar. Well, there are also some complaints that winmanager is not under good maintenance . Sometimes it needs modification to the source code to work with NERDTree.

I would suggest you try winmanager first. If it does not work, you may try my stupid but useful work around:

```
function! ToggleNerdtreeTagbar()

    " check if NERDTree and Tagbar are opened
    let NERDTree_close = (bufwinnr('NERD_tree') == -1) 
    let Tagbar_close   = (bufwinnr('__Tagbar__') == -1) 

    TagbarToggle
    NERDTreeToggle

    if NERDTree_close && Tagbar_close
        wincmd K
        wincmd b
        wincmd L
        wincmd h
        exe 'vertical resize 30'
    endif

endfunction
nmap <C-e> :call ToggleNerdtreeTagbar()<CR>
```

This will work if 1) taglist or tagbar is on the leftside, 2) you open only one a window at first, then press CTRL-e. You can open other windows then.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I get to knew there is  winmanage.I searched it and get many helpful information!